# Como pegar um parâmetro em uma URL e atribuir a ele um novo valor?

Tags: jquery, url

Falando do meu problema, queria que ao passar uma URL com o código logo abaixo demonstrado, no meio do processo fosse trocado um parâmetro mas especificamente o parâmetro `pagina` que deve ir com `value = 1`.

```
// FILTROS
$('#ordem').on('change', function(){
    var url = $(this).val();
    if(url != ''){
        window.open(url, '_self');
    }   
});
```

A URL:

```
http://.../busca?&area_de=50&area_at=200&ordenacao=mxvalor&pagina=2
```

Dentro do código jQuery demonstrado, gostaria que a cada vez que fosse feito um filtro representado por `ordenacao` voltasse para a pagina 1 ou simplesmente removesse o parametro e sua value, o que fara com que minha aplicação volte automaticamente a pagina 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `live` está deprecado...

Comment: Já tentou então guardar a URL numa variável sem o parâmetro pagina e só concatenar ele quando preciso? Nesse caso quando fosse ter que redirecionar para a pagina sem parâmetro você utilizaria sua variável e nos demais casos você utilizaria suaurl + '?parametro'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que o seu select tem valores de URL e só quer mudar o valor da página ao que obtem do `this.vaue` pode fazer assim:

```
$('#ordem').on('change', function(){
    var url = this.value;
    if(!url) return;
    window.open(url.replace(/pagina=[\d]+/, 'pagina=1'), '_self');
});
```

A parte nova é `url.replace(/pagina=[\d]+/, 'pagina=1')`. Se colocar o seu HTML posso colocar um exemplo também.