# Receber parâmentro de URL por JS (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Preciso capturar um parâmetro de uma URL, por exemplo:

```
http://site.com/paginas/**nome-da-pagina**
```

Preciso capturar o **nome-da-pagina** com JS ou jQuery.

Comment: Creio que existe uma resposta para essa pergunta aqui no SOpt, aqui ne endereço: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38690/como-pegar-um-par%C3%A2metro-em-uma-url-e-atribuir-a-ele-um-novo-valor

Comment: Estou usando URL amigável, neste tutorial eles usam por exemplo: pagina.php=?pagina=nome-da-pagina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você quer o valor depois da última barra, usando o `location.href` e a função lastIndexOf que retorna índice da última posição do valor que foi passado nesse caso a /. + 1 (pois o indice começa em zero) para pegar a partir da barra.

```js
var url = location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
alert(url);
```

Comment: Isso!!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ViniciusSilva, se a resposta do colega Laerte te serviu, marque ela.